# How to edit row on a Jtable with Table CellEditor

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtable, tablecelleditor

I have a frame with a table that get features from database (feature that correspond to the search). Here's the table :

```
 public JTable getTableBornes() {
    if(TableBornes==null){

        TableModel TableBornesModel = 
            new DefaultTableModel(
                    new String[][] { { "", "", "" } },
                    new String[] { "Nom", "X", "Y" });
        TableBornes = new JTable();

        TableBornes.setModel(TableBornesModel);
        TableBornes.setBorder(new LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0,0,0), 1, false));
        TableBornes.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);

                }
    return TableBornes;

}
```

What I want to do is, when the user click on a cell and edits it, this must be done on the database too. I tried to add a listener to the `cellEditor` like this:

```
     addBornes.getTableBornes().getCellEditor()
            .addCellEditorListener(new CellEditorListener() {

                @Override
                public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) {

                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < rowsToActOn().length; i++) {

                            String name = addBornes.getTableBornes()
                                    .getValueAt(rowsToActOn()[i], 0)
                                    .toString();
                            Double x = new Double(addBornes
                                    .getTableBornes()
                                    .getValueAt(rowsToActOn()[i], 1)
                                    .toString());
                            Double y = new Double(addBornes
                                    .getTableBornes()
                                    .getValueAt(rowsToActOn()[i], 2)
                                    .toString());

                            String updateQuery = "UPDATE bornes_salemed_valid SET  x='"
                                    + x
                                    + "', y='"
                                    + y
                                    + "', name='"
                                    + name
                                    + "'";


                            PostgisDataStoreDriver postgisDataStore = (PostgisDataStoreDriver) context
                                    .getWorkbenchContext()
                                    .getRegistry()
                                    .getEntries(
                                            DataStoreDriver.REGISTRY_CLASSIFICATION)
                                    .get(0);

                            java.sql.Connection connx = postgisDataStore
                                    .getConn();
                            Statement st;
                            st = connx.createStatement();
                            st.executeUpdate(updateQuery);
                            connx.setAutoCommit(false);
                            connx.commit();
                            try {
                                refreshDataStoreLayerPlugin
                                        .execute(context);
                            } catch (Exception e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void editingCanceled(ChangeEvent e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

But am getting this exception:

> the cell editor is null

I don't know how to declare it and where exactly? Please help.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.vividsolutions.jump.workbench.ui.plugin.specific.ModifierBornesPlugIn.execute(ModifierBornesPlugIn.java:305)
            at com.vividsolutions.jump.workbench.plugin.AbstractPlugIn$1.actionPerformed(AbstractPlugIn.java:130)
            at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
            at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
```

Comment: I can see where this error occurs in your code, can you highlight where it occurs please?

Comment: it occurs in this line :  addBornes.getTableBornes().getCellEditor()

Comment: `getCellEditor` will only return a non-null value when the table is actually editing the cell. You should actually be monitoring the `TableModel` for changes directly

Comment: unrelated: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 2):

- remove all code about DB Connection from this code
- whats is CellEditorListener probably don't to use code without deepest knowledge about Java, Swing, JTable and XxxTableCelEditor

---

possible scenario

- never to open execute close Connection on fly in this case (long and hard Object), Connection could be opened on background from Workers Thread (there isn't important EDT at all) together with JTable
- add TableModelListener to JTable, returns proper coordinates to last edited cell,
- JTable doesn't returns previous value before Editort comited an new value to the XxxTableModel
- better could be to use AbstractTableModel, then you will fire another background task from setValueAt(), use SwingWorker (for enjoy) or Runnable#Thread (for production code), please you can to pretty ignore my last two commnets inside (....)

---

- I think there must exist `AbstractTableModel` with `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE` implemented as methods in the model directly

Comment: if i remove all the code about DB Connection, how could i get the current connection ( because i've already opened the connection and i want to edit the feature ).
if i use AbstractTableModel do i have to adapt all the method for that?
i used a tableModelListener and i overrided the tableChanged method but i don't get any changes in the data base. :s

Comment: Connection could be active untill JTable is visible on the screen, faster connection from embeded DB is about 250m.s. then creating and ResultSet / PreparedStatement, executing ..., your GUI freeze 0,3 - 1second, execute only PreparedStatements invoked from SwingWorker or Runnable#Thread, then all notifiers from TableCellEditor are done (setValueAt is called) immediatelly, and Workers thread has nothing to do with JTable, TableCellEditor, its XxxTableModel, nor with EDT, without any inpact to Swing GUI, its performance, nor to freeze

Comment: Statement/ PreparedStatements / Resultset could be close() in finally block (is executed in all cases from finally block), otherwise those Object stays in JVM memory (increasing) untill current JVM exists